# How should one configure or install salt-cloud to use the Saltstack py3 repository to install the minion instead of the distribution (apt) repository?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I would like salt-cloud to install the salt-minion using the same `sources.list.d/saltstack.list` file that is on the saltmaster server, but it uses the Ubuntu APT repository instead.

What I get on a new minion in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list`:

`deb https://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/18.04/amd64/latest bionic main`

What I want:

`deb https://repo.saltstack.com/py3/ubuntu/18.04/amd64/latest bionic main`

I installed salt-master and salt-cloud from the Saltstack repository by doing the following on my saltmaster server:

```sh
wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/py3/ubuntu/18.04/amd64/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://repo.saltstack.com/py3/ubuntu/18.04/amd64/latest bionic main" > etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list
apt update
apt install python3-pip salt-master salt-minion salt-cloud
```

I spin up a server using salt-cloud and the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list` without fail uses the apt repository, not the py3 repository.

**Is there an option I can set in the saltmaster configuration file that defines which repository salt-cloud should use? Is there a similar option in a salt-cloud profile that can be passed to the salt bootstrap script?**

I see in the bootstrap script that salt-cloud runs (found at bootstrap.saltstack.com) a command line option called `_CUSTOM_REPO_URL`, but I don't know how to pass options to that script when creating a server with `salt-cloud -p`

Happy to ask elsewhere (please indicate where) if more appropriate.

I can provide applicable parts of my salt-cloud profile if needed.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/ is a better fit.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask there too, but my question/situation feels more salt-stack related than Ubuntu related. There isn't even a tag for salt-stack on askubuntu.com, so it seems more likely that people interested in Salt will see my question here.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't really know what salt stack is, but it seems like a bunch of ubuntu commands to me which is usually off-topic for SO which is about programming questions and answers. See [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The ubuntu tag says "This tag should be used only for WRITING OR RUNNING PROGRAMS specifically in Ubuntu 18.04". Better not to cross-post, and you have an upvote so probably keep it here for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/cloud/deploy.html#deploy-script-arguments

That led me to add the following to my cloud server profile used with the `salt-cloud -p` command:

```
script: bootstrap-salt
script_args: -x python3
```

Then the correct repository was installed.